# Exit spark job without initing SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark

is it possible to exit spark job successfully, without initializing spark context ?
For cases like input file being empty.
This is needed because let's say I requested 4 executors without dynamic allocation. And until 4 are available, my job will wait, when I could have exited a lot earlier.

I am submitting yarn cluster job through spark-submit.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide code snippet for your case ?

Comment: You can check input file before creating spark context with hadoop FileStatus class:
`val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration()); if (hdfs.getFileStatus(PATH).length != 0) createSparkContext`

Comment: @prudenko, If for what ever reason sparkcontext is not created  job will fail. So is there some flag or config value I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You should open spark context even it is just empty context like this:

```
def get_spark_context(): 
     from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
     from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
     spark_conf = ....

     conf = SparkConf().setAppName("your_app")

     for key, value in spark_conf.items():
         conf.set(key, value)


     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
     sc.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/test/")
     spark = SparkSession(sc)
     return spark
```

then you can call

```
if "do_something":
   "your real spark code"
else: # this part is do nothing part
   spark = get_spark_context()
   print("there is no need to run spark")
```